# a single vocabulary item as synonym for hidden fees

Tags: single-word-requests

There is a word I remember seeing some time ago, but unfortunately I have now forgotten.

The definition was like this:
to pay an amount which is more than expected, similar to *hidden fees*.

I think it was a verb or noun. For example, you buy something but there are hidden fees and you have to pay extra.

Please help me out.

Comment: _RyanAir_, perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking ***overpay***?

Comment: You may be overcharged because of accessory costs!

Comment: *Tax*! The ultimate hidden fee--noun and verb.

Comment: And then there's the *graft*.

Comment: The price does not include an obligatory **supplementary charge** ** for our CEO's holiday fund, protection money, fines for prostitution and the bribing of public officials. **Plus VAT.

Answer (score 7):

You may be thinking of "[surcharge](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/surcharge.asp)" - which is commonly used to rip folks off while sounding professional - and somehow justified.

Comment: +1.  Thank you for buying your ticket via the TicketMaster website.  There's an additional $10 processing surcharge.  Which powers our servers, or something.  In fact, we have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

***[Tax](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tax)***

> NOUN
>
> 1. A compulsory contribution to state revenue, levied by the government on workers' income and business profits, or **added to the
>      cost of some goods, services, and transactions**:
>
> VERB
>
> 1. Impose a tax on (someone or something):

Wouldn't everyone love to forget *tax*, at least for a season.

Comment: It depends where you are, but in many countries most taxes aren't hidden at all.